# schema.org - Can a "Restaurant" be part of a "ItemPage"?

Tags: html, semantics

I'm new to schema.org and trying to describe a website for a
restaurant. Basically the website looks like this:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemPage">
   <div itemprop="breadcrumb">...</div>
   <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Restaurant">...</div>
</body>
```

Is it valid to place a "Restaurant" (Thing->Organization...) within
the scope of a "Itempage" (Thing->CreativeWork)? The documentation
shows that the "Restaurant" is not part of the scope of a "ItemPage".
On the other hand the "ItemPage" is described "A page devoted to a
single item, such as a particular product or hotel.". So a hotel is
similar to a restaurant ;) Is this type of nesting valid?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need the ItemPage as part of the body. You can just start specifying the restaurant in one of the divs, then make sure the rest of the properties are defined as children. Like so:

```
<body>
    <div>...</div>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Restaurant">
        <span itemprop="name">McDonald's</span>
        <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
            <span itemprop="streetAddress">1234 Smith Ave</span>
            <span itemprop="addressLocality">Seattle</span>
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: And where does he fit the breadcrumb?....thats why he needs the ItemPage or WebPage.